# Running actions in sequence SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In my iOS App I'm trying to animate the distribution of the cards to all of the players. However, when I try to run the action sequence, none of my cards move. What am I doing wrong?

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    var actions = [SKAction]()
    let cards = makeDeck()
    for c in cards {
        let card = Card(key: c)
        card.position = CGPointMake(300, 300)
        addChild(card)
        actions.append(SKAction.moveTo(giveCardToPlayer(cards.indexOf(c)!), duration: 2.0))
    }
    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))
}
```

Comment: There are two things: 1) probably you use Swift 3 beta, otherwise you syntax is wrong, so add the relevant tag to your question. 2) you should post your code about giveCardToPlayer to better understand what happened, probably this function return the same card.position.

Comment: You are moving the scene (self),  you want to put actions on cards

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))
```

To

```
cards.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actions))
```

Currently, you are running the sequence of actions on the scene rather than the cards.

Without seeing any of the other code I'd assume this is correct, however if this doesn't help I suggest posting the code from giveCardToPlayer